# Format column using JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, json

I want to format a column if there is a date in the column, otherwise leave it blank.

This is the code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "debugMode": true,
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(@currentField == '','','sp-field-severity--good')"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 4px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
  ]
}
```

No matter if there is a date or not, the field is highlighted.  I don't want the highlight if blank.  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change your expression to look at the `displayValue` portion of the date for a better way to check for blanks:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "debugMode": true,
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(@currentField.displayValue == '','','sp-field-severity--good')"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 4px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below JSON code to format column.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "=if(@currentField, @currentField, 'Null')",
    "attributes": {
        "class": "=if(@currentField, 'sp-field-severity--good', '')"
    }
}
```

[image]

========================= **Updated Answer** ========================

**Please use the below JSON:**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "=if(@currentField, toDateString(@currentField), 'Null')",
    "attributes": {
        "class": "=if(@currentField, 'sp-field-severity--good', '')"
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked!  But...how do I show just the date and not the time?

Comment: Hi llrinct. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!